# Pass multiple ajax data to form using asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

I am trying to pass jquery data values to another page's form. I've tried the suggested solutions I found in the net but still no luck.

On my [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYqUB.png), the solution I am thinking is to add the data to my href and from there extract the values and add to my fields. Here is the code I am trying but failed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    dataTable = $('#DT_employees').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 50,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/Employees",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "employeeId", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "userName", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "firstName", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "lastName", "width": "10%" },
            {
                "data": "{employeeId, firstName, lastName}",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="w-75 btn-group">
                                <a href = "/Trainees/Index?=${data}" class="btn btn-primary text-white">
                                </a>
                            </div>`
                },
                "width": "5%"
            }
        ],
        "width": "100%"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example, but I use the `full` property of DataTable, you can use it as a reference.

Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Employees()
{
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee() { employeeId=1,userName="Tom Smith",firstName="Smith",lastName="Tom"},
        new Employee() { employeeId=2,userName="Jim Willer",firstName="Willer",lastName="Jim"}
    };
    return Json(employees);
}
```

(HomeController)Index.cshtml:

```
<table id="DT_employees">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>employeeId</th>
            <th>userName</th>
            <th>firstName</th>
            <th>lastName</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $('#DT_employees').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 50,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/Employees",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json",
                "dataSrc": function (d) {
                     return d
                  }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "employeeId", "name": "employeeId", "width": "10%" },
                { "data": "userName", "name": "userName", "width": "10%" },
                { "data": "firstName","name": "firstName", "width": "10%" },
                { "data": "lastName", "name": "lastName", "width": "10%" },
                {
                    "render": function (data,type,full,meta) {
                        return `<div class="w-75 btn-group">
                                    <a href = "/Trainees/Index?employeeId=${full.employeeId}&firstName=${full.firstName}&lastName=${full.lastName}" class="btn btn-primary text-white">details
                                    </a>
                                </div>`
                    },
                    "width": "5%"
                }
            ],
            "width": "100%"
        });
    });
</script>
```

TraineesController:

```
public IActionResult Index(Employee employee)
{
    return View(employee);
}
```

(TraineesController)Index.cshtml:

```
@model Project.Models.Employee

<div>
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeId)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.employeeId)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.firstName)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.firstName)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lastName)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.lastName)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, it is the one I've been searching the whole time!
Thanks for the help @Chen, I really appreciate it!